# Has Black Widow ever been imbued with Spider-Powers?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, powers, black-widow

I'm aware that there are many Spider-People of various flavors (see *Into the Spider-Verse*) and all kinds of storylines where others have been temporily imbued with Spider-Powers.

Lo and behold, Black Widow is named after a spider...

**Have there ever been any storylines where the Black Widow has Spider-Man-type powers?**

In this case, *Spider-Powers* must rise above the level of super strength, resilience and reactions (unless they are specifically imbued by interaction with a spider or a Spider-Person).   Examples of acceptable powers regardless of how received would be skills like web-slinging, wall-crawling, and Spidey-sense.

Comment: Canon or otherwise?

Comment: @Valorum:   I was assuming comic-book canon.   What else would there be?   Your father's brother's mechanic's former roommate wrote a story?

Comment: Well, there are also books, TV shows, games and movies not to mention plastic toys, lunchboxes and of course, [fidget spinners](https://cdn-cosmos.bluesoft.com.br/products/3002503689253)

Comment: “Black Widow is named after a spider” *[citation needed]*

Comment: @Valorum:   I guess I will take the answers to whatever level of canonicity they speak.   Certain though the highest level of canonicty should be prioritized.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - The Russians also had a male who was taken through the same training program. He was dubbed the "Wolf Spider" which implies that the naming is animal-based.

Comment: @Valorum: They couldn't have just called him Black Widower. For shame, comrades.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite she has at times used a symbol that looks like the markings on a black widow spider

Answer (score 50):

Black Widow, along with half of Manhattan, receives viral spider powers in the animated series [*Marvel's Spider Man - Spider Island Part 2*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7866168/).

We don't see her use spidey-sense, but she slings web, crawls on walls, leaps high into the air and punches like a champion,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, the "along with half of Manhattan" makes this not as satisfying as it could be.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Beggars, alas, cannot be choosers

Answer (score 28):

Kind of.

In the Ultimate Marvel universe/line of comics, the original (Natasha Romanova) Black Widow dies, and a couple of other characters take up the name while working for SHIELD.

One of the other characters who takes the name Black Widow is the [Ultimate version of Spider-Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman_(Ultimate_Marvel_character)), a female clone of Peter Parker who most definitely has spider powers.

While this is not *the* Black Widow of the main 616 universe, or a direct parallel copy, she is a Black Widow. She fills a similar role as a covert operative for SHIELD as the previous two did in the Ultimates Universe. I would see this as similar to how we've had stuff like Sam Wilson as Captain America for a while instead of Steve Rogers, or Miles Morales as another Spider-Man.

Comment: I'm not really sure this applies. She's not Black Widow, she just uses the name.

Comment: @Valorum, I'd still say she is a Black Widow, but it depends how you choose to define the character. Much like there are many Spider Men, and not all are Peter Parker. Also hence the "kind of".

Comment: Well argued. +1 from me for the edit.

Comment: This is a good answer and not what I expected.   If I wanted to nitpick, I could argure that this is not Black Widow getting "imbued" with Spider-Powers.   It's a Spider-Person taking on the mantled of Black Widow.    Imbuing implies the transfer of powers into...

Comment: @BoogaRoo:   That's not my point.   I'm not questioning whether this Black Widow is a true Black Widow.   I'm simply stating that this Black Widow didn't **gain** the powers.   She already has the powers and **then** became Black Widow.

Comment: A name by any other rose?

Comment: @BoogaRoo:   Getting Spider-Powers and then taking on the name *Spider-Man* is not the same thing as having Spider-Powers, being Spider-Woman and then taking on the name *Black Widow*.   The name *Black Widow* isn't associated with those powers, so taking on that mantle is different than taking on a Spider-Name ***because*** of newly acquired Spider-Powers.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Yes, but your question was, and I quote "Have there ever been any storylines where the Black Widow has Spider-Man-type powers?" It did not specify that she had to gain them after acquiring the name Black Widow.

Answer (score 26):

As far as I'm aware Black Widow has never had physical Spider-Man-like powers. *However*, in *Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1* Issue 86 Black Widow upgrades her costume and equipment. As part of that process she upgrades her Widow's Line: an imitation of Spider-Man's web shooters.

[image: Black Widow's Widow Lines in action]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Her suits have also been shown to be able to cling to walls and climb them due to suction cups in it as we see in the same issue with her previous suit.

[image: Black Widow's wall climbing abilities]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

It's worth noting that in this issue she wanted to interrogate Spider-Man to work out how his powers worked. She realises though that they are natural to him and not created through some other means and so soon drops that pursuit.

Answer (score 0):

No, she never has had spider powers in canon, (to my knowledge) but in the mighty avengers run she wore a version  of the iron spider suit.